# Contar caracteres de um textarea classe summernote. Não conta os caracteres CSS, como por exemplo <b>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um contador de caractres que funciona bem para texto sem condições especiais, por exemplo um texto sem negrito nenhum funciona muito bem, porém ,se eu coloco negrito no texto, o contador não reconhece o `<b>`, e assim a substituição não funciona, pois o ponto de inicio e fim ficam incorretos. Como posso contar os caracteres que ficam escondidos, como por exemplo os caracteres que deixam o texto negrito?

```
$j2(document).on("change", ".abre", function(evt){

var selection = document.getSelection('#m_summernote_1');
//conta inicio da palavra selecionada
var start5 = selection.anchorOffset;
//conta final da palavra selecionada
var finish5 = selection.focusOffset;

//texto que irá substituir a palavra seleciona
var textot = $j2("#valor option:selected").val();

//texto completo do textarea
var textoc = $j2('#m_summernote_1').val();

//aqui eu limpo o texto original , apagando a partir do ponto incicial start5 e finish5
var delText = textoc.substr(0,start5)+''+textoc.substr(finish5);

// aqui coloco o texto que irá substituir a palavra selecionada
var addText = textoc.substr(0,start5)+textot+delText.substr(start5);

//aqui eu substituo o texto do textarea
$("#m_summernote_1").summernote("code", addText);
});
```

Comment: `var textoc = $j2('#m_summernote_1').text();`

Comment: opa, a mudança de val por text neste caso não mudou em nada, pois o texto ele está pegando completo. o que me parece ter alguma incompatibilidade seria neste ponto: var selection = document.getSelection('#m_summernote_1');
//conta inicio da palavra selecionada
var start5 = selection.anchorOffset;
//conta final da palavra selecionada
var finish5 = selection.focusOffset; talvez o anchorOffSet e o focusOffSet não reconheçam o texto com os caracteres especias, por exemplo eles não contam o <b> inicial de um texto.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa escutar o evento `onChange` da própria instância do summernote que por sua vez vai te passar 2 parâmetros via callback `contents` e `$editable`, onde contents é a string com as tags html e com a string em mão basta chamar o lenght para contar o número de caracteres dela.

Com isso em mente segue o exemplo da própria [documentação](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange)

```js
$('#m_summernote_1').summernote({
    callbacks: {
        onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
            console.log(contents);
            console.log('Tamanho da string: ', contents.length);
            // console.log('onChange:', contents, $editable);
            // restante de sua lógica aqui...
        }
    }
});
```

Ou caso já tenha instanciado o summernote você pode escutar o evento personalizado que o plugin emite. Veja:

```
// summernote.change
$('#m_summernote_1').on('summernote.change', function(we, contents, $editable) {
    console.log(contents);
    console.log('Tamanho da string: ', contents.length);
    // console.log('onChange:', contents, $editable);
    // restante de sua lógica aqui...
});
```